# calculating $y$ from the equation $u^Tv=x^Ty$ (all vectors)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Is it possible to calculate $y$ from the equation $u^Tv=x^Ty$ , where $x,y,u, v$ are all vectors? Assume $u,v,x$ are known and $y$ is unknown. Moreover, all the vectors have the same size, $n\times1$. We assume $y_i>0,~ x_i\ge 0,~v_i\ge0, 0\le u_i\le1 ~\forall i\in(1,\ldots,n)$ and $\sum_i^n u_i=1$.

Comment: It's multiplication.

Comment: Multiplication as in...?

Comment: How do you multiply two vectors? For example, what is $(x_1,x_2)*(y_1,y_2)$?  Or do you mean the cross-product?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom u'*v shows the inner product between u and v. The prime denotes the transpose operation.

Comment: Okay, so you're using Matlab notation. Keep in mind that in general (in the broad arena of mathematics), "vectors" and "column-vector matrices" are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k = u^Tv \in \Bbb R$.  The equation you are solving for $y$ is
$$
x^Ty = k
$$
That is, given constants $k$ and $x_i$ you're trying to solve the equation
$$
x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n = k
$$
for the variables $y_i$.  If $x \neq 0$ and $n > 1$, this system of equations will necessarily have infinitely many solutions.

---

Given your new constraints, the system you describe will have infinitely many solutions when $x \neq 0$.  In particular: let $i$ be such that $x_i > 0$.  We have the solution
$$
y_j = 
\begin{cases}
k/x_i & j = i\\
0 & j \neq i
\end{cases}
$$
Moreover, your set of solutions will form a closed convex set.  That is to say: let $t$ be an arbitrary value between $0$ and $1$. If $y_1,y_2$ are solutions to your system, then $y_1 + (1-t)y_2$ is another solution.

Also, if any of the $x_i$ are $0$, then changing the corresponding entry $y_i$ of a vector $y$ does not affect whether $y$ is a solution.

Comment: Even if we assume $y_i>0 ~\forall i\in(1,\ldots,n)$ we would have infinitely many solutions? How can we limit the answer set?

Comment: No, that assumption changes things quite a bit. We'd need to know more about $x$ and $k$.

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: ${}$see my edit

Comment: In the constraints, I put $y_i>0~\forall i , 1\le i\le n$, but in your answer $y_j$ for $j\neq i$ could be zero. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I was using $y_i \geq 0$.